# Creating Cloud Build trigger from Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-build, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to create a Cloud Build trigger from Terraform but I am getting "Blocks of type "github" are not expected here." error.

My code:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "3.5.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "google" {
  credentials = file("key-file.json")

  project = var.project_id
}

resource "google_cloudbuild_trigger" "github-trigger" {
  name = "github-trigger"
  filename = "cloudbuild.yaml"
  location = "europe-west1"
  github {
    owner = <owner>
    name = <name>
    push {
      branch = <branch>
    }
  }
    
}
```

When I am not including github block and location, the code is working and the trigger is being created.

My encoding is UTF-8 and I am running the code in VS Code.

Any idea why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using provider version that is three years old, it will not work that way. You can either update to a newer version that supports `github` argument or make sure you are using the correct syntax for the provider version you have. My guess is that the closest to what you want is using `trigger_template` block [1] where you can define similar arguments:

- `project_id`
- `repo_name`
- `dir`
- `branch_name`
- `tag_name`
- `commit_sha`

However, I strongly suggest updating to a newer provider version.

---

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/3.5.0/docs/resources/cloudbuild_trigger#trigger_template